Creating and managing a geodatabase from Excel
I am trying to figure out and then build the correct type of geodatabase for my program area. I have a pretty comprehensive layout of the GDB in Excel- basically, I built an attribute table in Excel showing what fields/alias/domains are wanted for each feature class and listed in the desired order. My dream scenario would be to adjust my excel sheet for correct formatting (whatever that might be), but then I could import that Excel sheet and it would generate the GDB fields and feature classes. Absolutely no clue if this is even possible. My main concern is consistency across feature classes/fields/domains.
In the past, I feel like I've had to build and rebuild GDBs because I left something out the first time, or we reworked the field orders, or something like that. I would like to be able to set up the GDB correctly the first time with all associated data. I need to be able to either copy and paste or append additional data as it is collected in Field Maps and right now we have an empty copy of our geodatabase as a hosted feature layer in AGOL where we collect data in (to make sure all the fields match up). I'm not sure if the relationship between ArcGIS Pro (desktop) generated data and AGOL/Field Maps/Hosted Feature Layer generated data would cause an issue with compatibility.
And in case it isn't obvious, I am very much learning on the fly and as I go!

I understand your situation, what you're trying to do isn't achievable directly, you could try creating an XML workspace schema then import that https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/import-xml-workspace-document.htm - XML is a little more flexible and it's easy to apply. If you can find a way to export your Exel to a suitable XML schema this would be optimal. Start by exporting one geodatabase to see how the fields and feature classes are expressed in a schema document.

Geodatabase Diagrammer was a very good tool https://hub.arcgis.com/content/a378b48be11b45b5bb25254643304cb7/about
